# How to make Helm install to use 'kubectl apply' instead of 'kubectl create'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When we run `helm install ./ --name release1 --namespace namespace1`, it creates the chart only if none of the deployments exist then it fails saying that the deployment or secret or any other objects already exist.

I want the functionality to create Kubernetes deployment or objects as part of helm install only those objects or deployments already not exists if exists helm should apply the templates instead of creating.

I have already tried 'helm install' by having a secret and the same secret is also there in the helm templates, so helm installs fail.

Comment: did you run with latest version of `helm`?

Comment: Using Helm 2.9.1, i don't think helm has a feature to update existing object (like **kubectl apply**) instead of create as part **helm install**.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, I would try [`helm upgrade`](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-upgrade).

Comment: Yes I know it works with upgrade, but we want it with **helm install**, this is for one of the secret, we have dependency with security team they supposed to create a secret before my product deployment, but in dev environment we want to create the security. I want under impression that Helm has a feature to tell that specific object update instead of create. Seems helm do not have such feature as of now.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done without modifying the `helm` code

Answer (score 3):

In recent helm versions you can run `helm upgrade --install` which does an upgrade-or-install.

Another alternative is you can use `helm template` to generate a template and pipe it to `kubectl apply -f -`. This way you can install or upgrade with the same command.

Comment: `helm template` with `kubectl apply` doesn't work in all cases because some charts run pre/post-install/upgrade hooks, look at GitLab helm chart for example.